# What is this plant?

Tags: botany, species-identification

It was found in Eastern Pennsylvania (in the United States) in a deeply wooded area.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Those are the fruit clusters of a common "wildflower" that often grow in wet areas, called [Eastern Skunk Cabbage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplocarpus_foetidus) or Symplocarpus *foetidus*.  Initially (early Spring), it's not bad looking (and some species - such as the western skunk flower - are even pretty):

[image]    [image]

But after a while, the spathe (sheath) dries up while the seeds grow in the spadix (the fleshy thing in the middle with the little 'flowers') grow, leaving the swollen spadix (fruit):

[image] [image]

The tip off, though, is the characteristic new growth, very skunk-cabbagey, so I would guess those fruits are from the previous year (?).

> - Eastern skunk cabbage is notable for its ability to generate temperatures of up to 15–35 °C (27–63 °F) above air temperature by cyanide resistant cellular respiration in order to melt its way through frozen ground, placing it among a small group of plants exhibiting thermogenesis.

This allows it to flower through melted ice or snow. Also:

- It's a member of the arum family.
- It depends for fertilization on bugs that like carrion.
- It's virtually impossible to dig up a well-established plant because the roots pull the plant down deeper into the soil every year (it has *contractile roots*).
- It was widely used medicinally.

<sub>[Skunk Cabbage (Symplocarpus foetidus)](http://natureinstitute.org/pub/ic/ic4/skunkcabbage.htm)</sub>

Comment: Some types can also be mistaken by the uninitiated for rhubarb, which it definitely is *not* :)

Comment: @MattDMo - Eeeeewww! The smell should be a tip off, no? I mean, they produce chemicals like "putrescine" and "cadaverine". I'll take rhubarb! (Now that I think about it, I can see a tiny resemblance maybe.)

Comment: it was a long time ago; I was young and innocent :) I'm not even sure if it was "true" skunk cabbage, but that's what someone else called it after I tried nibbling on a leaf stem and almost threw up. This was in central Pennsylvania, not far from where the OP found the specimens in the question.

Comment: @anongoodnurse Putrescine and cadaverine to attract flies? I have also noticed that flies get attracted to spermine/spermidine. I just left a solution (with some sugar) in an open bottle to see and in some days it had maggots. Tried this twice (not enough replicates :P).